# Send values from one python script to another one already running

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand how I can develop a system that is made from two python script running in a linux box.

The first one starts on system boot and always run, basically connects to a MQTT server and wait for the other python script. The second one is called from the command line, doing some works and then pass some data, basically three strings, to the first one and than exits.

Which way is the "correct" one to be used in this situation to pass data from script two to script one?

Comment: If you are doing Python development in 2019, you should definitely be targeting the recommended, supported version of the language, which is Python 3. By the original timeline, Python 2 would be dead already. It's a zombie; don't go near it.

Comment: yes, I know and you're right. But at the moment I have no possiblity to upgrade the linux box os or python package to a newer one

Comment: Python 3 can coexist with Python 2 on pretty much anything newer than Debian oldoldstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this (blocking and non-blocking). Depending on your MQTT server you could use it in a pub/sub approach to pass the data from the temporary script to the running one.

If that is not possible another pub/sub server could be used as e.g. [redis](https://redis.io/). Especially the pub/sub functionality of redis is very useful for this. `redis` is well supported in python.

Another more lightweight possibility is to use a `First In First Out` (FIFO) queue c.f. [article on using fifos in python](https://timmurphy.org/2013/11/11/using-fifos-in-python/) or [blocking vs. non-blocking fifos](http://kodedevil.com/2017/07/07/linux-fifos-python/)

FIFOs are easy to use if both processes run on the same computer. `redis` would be preferable if both scripts run on different computers.

There are more complex packages for inter-process communication around, e.g. [rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/),.. but they might be overkill for your use case...

Comment: I will try the FIFO approch, redis seems powerful but as a first attempt I think FIFO will be easier.

Comment: You might want to play around with blocking vs. non-blocking communication, depending on  if you have to wait for the output of the secondary script or if it is optional for your first script. I added a second reference on fifos to the answer.

Comment: I would be interested in how you implemented the communication between the scripts in the end.

Comment: Hi Ascurion, at the moment the system is running using a non blocking fifo and it's ok. Anyway I still need to implement some exception handling and testing it in real situation. Thank for your support

Comment: Glad I could help.